# media query not being picked up in IE

Tags: css, media-queries

I have the following test code in my css file:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 960px){
    body{
        background-color: red;
    }
    .wrapperShadow {
        margin: 0px 3em;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 2.5em 0.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    }
    .wrapperShadow {
        margin: 0px 3em;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 2.5em 0.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    }

 }
```

I added the red just as a test. 
But in IE, it's not picking this css as per the F12 tool
I'm just wondering what the problem could be.

**EDIT 1:**

What I'm noticing is that my site is defaulting to compatibility mode, on various pages. 
When I turn off compatibility mode using the little broken page symbol in the address bar, the page looks correct.
why does it default to compatibility mode? 
is it because I have the following line in my header:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" >
```

Comment: The version is IE version 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have compatibility mode turned on? Check that...

(IE9 Under "Compatibility View Settings" it had the "Display Intranet Sites in Compatibility View")

Good Luck..)

Comment: if the icon for compatibility mode is blue, does that mean its on?  sorry for the remedial questions.  I'm just new to css stuff

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, IE9 can understand @media queries, but earlier versions can't. If you hit f12 on a PC and then check Compatibility mode, you may find that it's running an earlier version.

I once saw this code to display a default image for sub-IE9 browsers:

Answer (score 1):

Ugh, actually it won't let me post the code. The workaround is at line 85 here: https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill/commit/9aa22f58cd338bdd22e907239cb33629a5ec2143

Answer (score 0):

With those meta tags you are telling ie to use the ie 7 view engine,yuck. When you remove those tags you will use either the 9 or 10 view engines.